# How to load past comments properly?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am currently trying to do a load previous comments function. I am using ajax and i have problems trying to make the onClick event to work. Any ideas?

Html Code:

```
<div id="workroom_boxes_chatpast" align="center">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="return getMessages();">Load older chats...</a>
</div>
<div id="chat_cleaner"></div>
<div id="chatcontent" align="center">Loading...</div>
```

Scripts:

```
function getMessages(){
    $("#workroom_boxes_chatpast").html('<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif"/>&nbsp; Loading...');

    $.ajax({
        url: "/recent/messages/{{ chat.key.id }}",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $("#chatcontent").html(html);
            $("#workroom_boxes_chatpast").hide();
        }
    });

    setTimeout('getMessages()', 4000);
});
```

Comment: you should use the jQuery click trigger rather than inline javascript.

Comment: @Lekis can you give me an example on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LekisS/WX4VG/1/ :)

Comment: @lekis is there a explanation why my method does not work and using your click trigger is better way of using? i realise i cannot do a setTimeout now using your method because i need to give this function a name in order to execute

Comment: Where is loaded your "getMessages" function ? It shouldn't be wrapped by any $(function()) or anything similar :). Otherwise it should be working

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark, but change the `$("#chatcontent").html(html);` to  `$("#chatcontent").html(html.d);`

Comment: MS returns a response in a `d` property: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Parsing-ClientScript-JSON.aspx

Comment: As Jakub said... Your question didn't give too many details as to what problems you're having (specifically), so it's really a guess as to what might be wrong.

Comment: @Farlig i am pretty sure my backend servers are working. When i Click the ahref, nothing happens- the page stays as it is..so i guess the loading is not working

Comment: @Farlig i managed to get it work using Lekis' solution which choose a click trigger instead of triggering through my current method. Is there a reason why people would want to choose my method to execute instead of using click function?

Comment: The way LekisS' solution works is by unobtrusively adding behavior to the page, which is the preferred way of adding behavior to page elements. Adding the behavior is dependent on JavaScript being enabled on the page, which it should be, considering the event handler it self IS JavaScript... Read up a bit on it.

Answer (score 0):

`getMessages` function doesn't return anything so do not write `return getMessages()` in `onclick`. You might want to write:

```
onclick="getMessages(); return false;"
```

to prevent jumping in some browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
var status="notloaded"; 

function getMessages(){

    $('#loading').hide();           

    if(status == "notloaded")
    {
        var myurl = "/recent/messages/id/10/status/notloaded"
        /**
        load older message
        **/
        status = "loaded"
    }
    else{
        var myurl = "/recent/messages/id/10/status/loaded"
        /**
        do not load older message
        **/
    }       

    $.ajax({
        url: myurl,
        /**
        Load new message
        **/
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){

            $('#loading').hide();
            $("#workroom_boxes_chatpast").hide();

        }
    });

    setTimeout('getMessages()', 4000);
});
```